Is there a way to retreive only specific event id and source from events rather than retriving all events?
I am able to retrieve all the events and filter them to retrieve the specific Id along with source. But instead of retrieving all of them, i want to retrieve only the events which i have given as eventId and source.
This is my code:

import win32evtlog
import datetime

log_type = "Security"
event_log_handle = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(None, log_type)

try:
    flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ | win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ
    
    start_time = datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 28, 0, 0, 0)
    end_time = datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 20, 23, 59, 59)
   
    print("Reading event log...")
    events_found = False  
    
    while True:
        events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(event_log_handle, flags, 0)
       
        if not events:
            break
       
        for event in events:
            event_id = event.EventID & 0xFFFF
            source = event.SourceName
            date_time_str = event.TimeGenerated.Format()
            date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
            if start_time <= date_time <= end_time and event_id == 4616 and source.lower() == "microsoft-windows-security-auditing":
                events_found = True
                computer_name = event.ComputerName
                event_data = event.StringInserts
                to_time = event_data[5]
                from_time = event_data[4]
                print(f"Found Event: Date/Time: {date_time_str}, Event ID: {event_id}, Source: {source}")
                print(f"Computer: {computer_name}, The system time has changed from: {from_time} to: {to_time}")
    
    if not events_found:
        print("No data available within the specified date range.")
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
finally:
    win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(event_log_handle)

